# How to redirect to my squid proxy using iptables since DNAT target: only valid in nat table

Tags: iptables, squid, nat

I want to redirect the traffic in my lan network through squid proxy but I am having some problems with `iptables` rules.

When I use the following rule:

```
# iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.196:3128
```

I get the following error:

```
x_tables: ip_tables: DNAT target: only valid in nat table, not filter
```

I have tried using `PREROUTING` chain but there is nothing like this in my iptables:

```
# iptables -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.196:3128
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

I am using iptables version `v.1.4.10`

```
# iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
prerouting_rule  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
zone_lan_prerouting  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
zone_wan_prerouting  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

my whole `iptables -nLv`

```
root@OpenWrt:~# iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  776 93902 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 3231  164K syn_flood  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x17/0x02 
 7098  429K input_rule  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 7096  429K input      all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           MAC XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX udp spt:22509  
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           MAC XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX tcp spts:59000:65399 
    0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           MAC XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX udp spts:49950:65399 
 8271 3071K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
  451 44484 forwarding_rule  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  451 44484 forward    all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    5   276 reject     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 7408  581K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  206 13814 output_rule  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  206 13814 output     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  446 44208 zone_lan_forward  all  --  br-lan *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 zone_wan_forward  all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain forwarding_lan (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain forwarding_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain forwarding_wan (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  515 43070 zone_lan   all  --  br-lan *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 6560  385K zone_wan   all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain input_lan (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain input_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain input_wan (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  206 13814 zone_lan_ACCEPT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  203 13301 zone_wan_ACCEPT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain output_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain reject (5 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 3249  166K REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with tcp-reset 
 3257  198K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 

Chain syn_flood (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 3231  164K RETURN     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x17/0x02 limit: avg 25/sec burst 50 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain zone_lan (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  515 43070 input_lan  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  515 43070 zone_lan_ACCEPT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain zone_lan_ACCEPT (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    3   513 ACCEPT     all  --  *      br-lan  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  515 43070 ACCEPT     all  --  br-lan *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain zone_lan_DROP (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      br-lan  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  br-lan *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain zone_lan_REJECT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 reject     all  --  *      br-lan  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    5   272 reject     all  --  br-lan *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain zone_lan_forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  446 44208 zone_wan_ACCEPT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    5   272 forwarding_lan  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    5   272 zone_lan_REJECT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain zone_wan (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   64 21010 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:68 
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 
 6496  364K input_wan  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 6496  364K zone_wan_REJECT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain zone_wan_ACCEPT (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  644 57237 ACCEPT     all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain zone_wan_DROP (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain zone_wan_REJECT (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 reject     all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 6496  364K reject     all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain zone_wan_forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 forwarding_wan  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 zone_wan_REJECT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Could you provide the output of `iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING`?

Comment: @Dave I have updated the answer

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify that the rule should go into the `nat` table, additionally DNAT commands need to go the PREROUTING chain and you need to be careful that you do not generate a loop.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i br-lan -s ! 192.168.1.196  -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.196:3128
```

The default table is the `filter` table.

Do not forget, that you also need MASQUERADE/SNAT to rewrite the source address:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
```

[This HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-6.html) provides more options and explanations.

Comment: I have just checked and I don't have FORWARD chain in nat table as shown here http://static.thegeekstuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/iptables-filter-nat-mangle-tables.png

Comment: @Patryk Thanks for the comment, there was another problem which I fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for help but this is still not working for me :/

Comment: @Patryk: Are your sure, that the problem is not on the squid side? It needs special setting if it should work as a transparent proxy.